# Twitter widget overlaps with Masonry

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, twitter

My website is using Masonry jQuery and I'm trying to incorporate the Twitter widget in it. Unfortunately it keeps on being overlapped by other bricks. [You can see a picture here.](http://i961.photobucket.com/albums/ae91/jan_tomes/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-09%20at%2010.09.37_zpsihmpijhn.png)

Now also the Facebook Page Plugin does that so I think the error must be in that Masonry loads first while both widgets work in iframes.

On various websites I've seen they found a solution to this, but I'm a total newbie in this and I'm lost. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: could you show us some code examples?

Comment: Sure! Also, I forgot to mention that the website is running on WordPress. Anyway, the Twitter Widget is a generated one on their site  and I load it in Masonry via php : `<?php 

  if( $cnt == 3  ){
  ?>
  <div class="masonry-sizer">
  
      <article id="post-custom<?php echo rand(99999,100000); ?>" class="post-custom post type-post status-publish hentry">

             here comes the Twitter code

  </article><!-- #post -->
    </div>

  <?php 
  }
?>`

Comment: I found it working on [this site](http://www.dazeddigital.com).